# Residual 'x' in preparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to write a class handling database interaction with a mysql server.
To do this i utilize 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar'.

I came across this behavior and am uncertain if I am making a mistake or found a bug.
The tested statement reads like this:

```
"INSERT INTO test.database.EncryptedClass (eMail) VALUES (?);"
```

I insert an encrypted value in byte[] form.

```
statement.setBytes(iterator, encryptedValue); // (iterator = 1)
```

The result is the following error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.EncryptedClass (eMail) VALUES (**x**'63EEAAA2F3CE444C9F1256FA8052F287CD96D67D29E2EB' at line 1

As you can see, there is an x in front of the actual value. I believe that is the variable which is supposed to be **replaced** by the actual value, but for some unknown reason, this fails, and instead, the value is appended.
If this is a bug, does it lie with the connector library or with the server itself.
I know this much: the values are actually infused in the database, but I am uncertain as to whether the value is already transmitted false, or if the database function replacing '?' with the value fails at doing so.

Comment: the `x` means that what follows is an hex string; your problem is much earlier in your query (just where mysql tells you "_near_")

Comment: What happens if you write that statement to the mysql command line interface? I believe the 'x' is marking that the following value is hexadecimal encoded bytes.

Answer (score 0):

guido and Kayaman are very much right.

The problem was the table name, which may not contain '.' characters.
The x before the value does identify it as hex value.